phone field is not updating when i filter my list in chrome mobile in os phones
i have a list that return a model that contains phone , name , country , city , ...etc
when i filter by name , country , city .. say the returned filtered data have 3 items

i got the following results :
in desktop or android devices : data and rendered data are ok;

in os phone trying from chrome :
request response data are right ,and rendered data too except phone is wrong.

after inspecting i found that :
requests have no debouce and throwtling so it have low time interval.

second i inspected the elements by remote debugging .. and i found element wrap my phone element called <chrome-annotate></chrome-annotate> and it contains data-attributes by wrong phones

when i checked network requests i found that the wrong phones values comes from first items in the first request happens in the page


<--! source vue file -->
<template>
<strong>
 {{item.phoneNumber}}
</strong>
</template>

<--! rendered html example -->
<chrome-annotate>
<strong>
 {{item.phoneNumber}}
</strong>
</chrome-annotate>


iam expecting the issue from number of requests in low time gap, makes chrome save the phone value
and something made chrome detect that is phone and cache it in requests changes


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
